# Chatting in Java?

Tags: java, chat, livechat

I am a Java beginner. I googled for one week for the solution. Now I'm posting this question. I want to develop a chat application in Java.

1. It is web based.
2. It need to chat with users in my company, by fetching the user list from my user table.
3. I don't want to chat with GTalk or Yahoo.

How can I achieve this? How can I check which users are online? How can I integrate this with my current website?

Comment: What you have done until now?

Comment: I have seen this question. :) re-posting?

Comment: possible duplicate of [java chat application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1582097/java-chat-application)

Comment: @ harry : I installed claros chat, but how can i make that to work with my data base?

Comment: @Stephen C : can u suggest a solution for this?

Comment: @kiran - your question is too vague to be answerable.

Comment: @Stephen C : ill provide any details u want? since im new to this i dbt i may choose a wrong tool ? its good to get a suggestion .

Comment: @Stephen C :waiting for u r reply..

Comment: @harry, stephen : still didnt get any solution ?...

Comment: @Kiran: You should try using Smack API.

Comment: @kiran - your question is too vague to be answerable.  So no, I cannot offer you an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I am surprised that you didn't find any Java chat server solutions after Googling. Just did a search for Java chat server and it returned 1.15million hits. The [first of which](http://java-source.net/open-source/chat-servers) was a list of open source Java chat server source codes.

Generally, writing server applications in Java is fairly easy, but if you are looking at a high volume chat application (>1000 users), I would recommend moving onto a different platform such as C++.

You will also need to provide some more information about your user list. Is it on a DB or AD etc.

Comment: It is on DB, I founf some chat server like claros, but thtats working with gtalk, how can i make that for my DB, from wer should i start, if u know any other plz suggest me

Comment: u having any experience with open fire?

Comment: i want to use jabber based client/server tool ? can u suggest me a tool

Answer (score 0):

You will need sockets to solve your Problem.

Look at at the ServerSocket class. 
http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html

call await in a while true loop (maybe in a new thread). It returns a new Socket (client Socket)

Save those in a List

have fun with it. :)

Comment: i think chat using socket is not scalable for my chat, it may have more than 50,000 users @ a time

Comment: @totkam : i want one that using jabber ? any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Java RMI too. Of course it won't require any Web Container. Using RMI and Multi threading you can come up with a fairly working Chat application.